# Simultaneous tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

While working through the review queue, I've come across multiple times when a tag wiki suggestion has been submitted by multiple users. Generally, I will at the minimum review them in terms of "can I Google what you wrote" and make sure it isn't plagiarism, and skip anything that I'm not qualified to say is correct. But there have been numerous times when I have found several suggestions that are all equally valid for the wiki. My question is, how should I, when only presented with one suggestion at a time, decide which is a valid suggestion? I can't see them all at once and pick the best, so I might just approve them all. Also, I don't want to reject one that is valid, just because another one might be more complete. As someone trusted with the sanctity of reviewing edit suggestions, what is the best course of action to take in situations like this?

As an (awful) example, suppose two users suggest:

> **banana**: a fruit that is largely associated with the consumption by primates

> **banana**: a fruit that is high in potassium and can be eaten to help prevent muscle cramps

Secondary to this, what happens when suggestion A is succeeded by suggestion B, and both are approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approving the tag wiki suggested edit creates a revision of that tag wiki, and approving the next tag wiki suggested edit creates another revision. So the latest one to be approved will be the one that appears. Until they're approved, though, they are only *suggested* edits.

Keep in mind that tag wikis, and tag wiki excerpts, have a full revision history, so if you run across a situation like this, you can check the revision history and edit the tag wiki again, reconciling the edits into a (hopefully) improved revision.

[image: Location of tag wiki history and excerpt history links]

Comment: I do appreciate the resources you point out, but they don't help for new tag wikis that have multiple suggestions in the queue.

Comment: If it's truly new, the first approved edit will cause Community ♦ to create a blank tag wiki, and the first approved edit will be revision 2. You can see an example of this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12372706/revisions).